# Store and retrive Listview data using Shared Preferences

Tags: android, mysql, database, listview, sharedpreferences

I have a listview of ringtones .. I feed the list via mysql database.. (such as song names,song urls ...).
I dynamically add products(ringtones) in my listview by adding new item in my database, so none of this data are inside my app except row icons.

***This is the view***

[image: This is the view]

As you can see I have a bookmark border icon that when user clicks on it, it will turn into selected...This is how it works :

```
    holder.favImage=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.favImage); 
    holder.favImage.setImageResource(product.getFavId());
    holder.favImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Product product = (Product) mDataItems.get(position);
            if(product.faved){
                product.setFavId(R.mipmap.bookmarked);
                sharedPreference.addFavorite(mContext,product);
                product.faved=false;
                }
            else {
                sharedPreference.removeFavorite(mContext,product);
                product.setFavId(R.mipmap.bookmark_border);
                product.faved = true;
                }
             notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

but nothing will happen in my "FAVORITES" tab .. Even the state of bookmark icon when it is selected will not be saved..

**Custom Adapter**

```
    public class FunDapter<T> extends BaseAdapter {


    protected List<T> mDataItems;
    protected List<T> mOrigDataItems;
    protected final Context mContext;
    private final int mLayoutResource;
    private final BindDictionary<T> mBindDictionary;

    SharedPreference sharedPreference;

    public FunDapter(Context context, List<T> dataItems, int layoutResource,
                     BindDictionary<T> dictionary) {
      this(context, dataItems, layoutResource, null, dictionary);
    }


    public FunDapter(Context context, List<T> dataItems, int layoutResource,
                     LongExtractor<T> idExtractor, BindDictionary<T> dictionary) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mDataItems = dataItems;
        this.mOrigDataItems = dataItems;
        this.mLayoutResource = layoutResource;
        this.mBindDictionary = dictionary;
        sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
    }



    public void updateData(List<T> dataItems) {
        this.mDataItems = dataItems;
        this.mOrigDataItems = dataItems;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (mDataItems == null || mBindDictionary == null) return 0;

        return mDataItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public T getItem(int position) {
        return mDataItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if(idExtractor == null) return position;
        else return idExtractor.getLongValue(getItem(position), position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        final GenericViewHolder holder;
        if (null == v) {
            LayoutInflater vi =
                    (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(mLayoutResource, null);
            holder = new GenericViewHolder();
            holder.root = v;


            //init the sub views and put them in a holder instance
            FunDapterUtils.initViews(v, holder, mBindDictionary);
            v.setTag(holder);
            }else {
            holder = (GenericViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }

        final T item = getItem(position);
        showData(item, holder, position);

    final Product product = (Product) mDataItems.get(position);        
    holder.favImage=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.favImage); 
    holder.favImage.setImageResource(product.getFavId());
    holder.favImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            if(product.faved){
                product.setFavId(R.mipmap.bookmarked);
                sharedPreference.addFavorite(mContext,product);
                product.faved=false;
                }
            else {
                sharedPreference.removeFavorite(mContext,product);
                product.setFavId(R.mipmap.bookmark_border);
                product.faved = true;
                }
             notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }); 


        return v;
    }

}
```

**Product model class**

```
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("pid")
    public int pid;

    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;

    @SerializedName("qty")
    public int qty;

    @SerializedName("price")
    public String description;

    @SerializedName("song_url")
    public String song_url;

    @SerializedName("date")
    public String date;


    public boolean paused = true;
    public boolean faved = true;

     private int favId;
    public int getFavId() {
        return favId;}
    public void setFavId(int favId) {
        this.favId = favId;} 
}
```

**SharedPreferences class**

```
   public class SharedPreference {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PRODUCT_APP";
    public static final String FAVORITES = "Product_Favorite";

    public SharedPreference() {
        super();
    }

    // This four methods are used for maintaining favorites.
    public void saveFavorites(Context context, List<Product> favorites) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        Editor editor;
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(favorites);
        editor.putString(FAVORITES, jsonFavorites);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void addFavorite(Context context, Product product) {
        List<Product> favorites = getFavorites(context);
        if (favorites == null)
            favorites = new ArrayList<Product>();
            favorites.add(product);
            saveFavorites(context, favorites);
    }

    public void removeFavorite(Context context, Product product) {
        ArrayList<Product> favorites = getFavorites(context);
        if (favorites != null) {
            favorites.remove(product);
            saveFavorites(context, favorites);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Product> getFavorites(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        List<Product> favorites;
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (settings.contains(FAVORITES)) {
            String jsonFavorites = settings.getString(FAVORITES, null);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Product[] favoriteItems = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites,Product[].class);
            favorites = Arrays.asList(favoriteItems);
            favorites = new ArrayList<Product>(favorites);
        } else
            return null;

        return (ArrayList<Product>) favorites;
    }
}
```

I'm stuck here for a few days, Can you help me please !

Comment: Can you please post your code in github and share the link.. I will try to fix it.

Comment: Can you give me explanation for this sentence 'New row will be added to the list when I insert new column in my database', because I am not understand what you say.

Comment: @RajaJawahar  It's uploading ,thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Actually your implementation more complex for the favorite, I thing simply take one column into your database like name isFavorite and by default added zero into this column when you press button then change value zero to one but every time we are not connected with internet so use SQLite database reason behind that size and speed of the SQLite database is more compare to SharedPreferences.
But here you not want to use SQLite database so first download json from the your web service and only change made when user click on the favorite button like
**Json format before click:**
{unieq_id:”1”, isFavorite :”0”}
**Json format after click:**
{unieq_id:”1”, isFavorite :”1”}
If isFavourite 0 then your non favorite icon display else display your favorite icon.